# How to paste date value with their format with vba?

Tags: excel, vba

Below code is working good except Date value. In my active sheet range B8, I have typed following formula (=TEXT(NOW(),"DD-MM-YYYY"))

But when I run below module it's always convert date format from **dd-mm-yyyy** to **mm-dd-yyyy** in Sheet3.

I have also formatted date column to custom date format (dd-mm-yyyy), but no luck.

```
lrow = Sheet3.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lrow = lrow + 1
Sheet3.Cells(lrow, 2).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Value 'Slip Number
Sheet3.Cells(lrow, 3).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Value 'Date
Sheet3.Cells(lrow, 4).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D8").Value 'Time
Sheet3.Cells(lrow, 5).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D9").Value 'Vehicle Number
Sheet3.Cells(lrow, 6).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D10").Value 'Total Vehicle Tyres
```

Not Working Method For Me

Module1.

```
Sheet3.Cells(lrow, 3).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Value 'Date

Sheet3.Cells(lrow, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") 'Date
```

Module2.

```
  'Date
  Sheets("Vehicle In Details").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("Vehicle Entry").Range("B8").Value
```

All Other Things are working good.

[image: Region Setting]

[image: Source Date Format]

[image: Destination Date Format]

Comment: what are your regional settings on windows? If it's set to American format, then hat could be what's overwriting it. Alternatively you can set custom format within the cell (Ctrl + 1). Another way of storing dates universally is to use yyyy-MM-dd. Give those a try and let us know

Comment: My Region is INDIA, and Regional Format Is English (INDIA), Using Windows 10 Build 1909. And PC Date Format is dd-mm-yyyy. But Time Format is 24 Hours Format.

Comment: Try to force the format of your destination cell before copy the value like this `Sheet3.Cells(lrow, 3).NumberFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"` (I'm not sure on upper or lowercase of day/month/year format).

Comment: No Luck Mr. Baro.

Comment: The simplest approach would be to enter the actual date (e.g. via `=NOW()`) into the source cell `B8` (only providing for the wanted numberformat) instead of transforming it  into text later or to assign values via `Sheet3.Cells(lrow, 3).Value = CDate(Sheet1.Range("B8").Value)` and to format eventually. @PrabhatVishwas

Comment: What is the cell date format in Tab: 'Vehicle in Details', Column C?

Comment: Dear @v-c0de, The whole column C are formatted as custom Format dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: Dear @T.M. still not working. This is a strange situation for me. I never face this types of critical problem.

Comment: Which approach did you choose: a) via date (only `=NOW()`) numberformatted in `B8` or b) via `CDate()` assignment? @PrabhatVishwas

Comment: Comment Part1: @T.M.
Step1. Windows Region Setting "INDIA", Windows Regional Format "English (INDIA)"
Step2. Sheet("Vehicle Entry") and Range B8 formula is =Today().
Step3. [Date shown as{03-11-2020 dd-mm-yyyy} format, and after running my First VBA code, the date value is Paste to Sheet("Vehicle In Details") Column C in good condition] Working Good.
Step4. Sheet("Vehicle Out") Range B8 formula is =IFERROR(IF(B6="","",VLOOKUP(B6,Vehicle_In_Details_Sheet,2,0)),"").

Comment: Comment Part2: @T.M.
Step5. [With this formula, I call the Date Value from Sheet("Vehicle In Details") Column C.
Step6. Date Visible in good condition as {04-11-2020 dd-mm-yyyy} format, But when I run my second VBA code which is almost same as my first VBA code, The date value are paste as 11-04-2020 format to Sheet("Vehicle Out Details") Column C] It is very bad.
Remarks: I have custom formated date columns and cells to dd-mm-yyyy.